# Oauth echo using elixir HTTPotion

Tags: curl, httprequest, elixir, phoenix-framework, twitter-digits

Im trying to verify twitter digits api on my phoenix framework/elixir backend... when im using curl it's succeeded, but i really don't know how to generate it using HTTPotion... I tried different combination but always returns "215", "Bad Authentication data."

> Here is my code when using curl

```
curl --get 'https://api.digits.com/1.1/sdk/account.json' --header 'Authorization: OAuth  oauth_signature="my-oauth-signature",oauth_nonce="my-oauty-nonce",oauth_timestamp="my-oauth-timestamp",oauth_consumer_key="my-oauth-consumer-key",oauth_token="my-oauth-token",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"' -v
```

> and this is so far what i tried to do using HTTPotion but still no
>   luck

```
HTTPotion.get "https://api.digits.com/1.1/sdk/account.json", [headers: ["Authorization": "OAuth", "oauth_consumer_key": "my-oauth-consumer-key", "oauth_nonce": "my-oauth-nonce", "oauth_signature": "my-oauth-signature", "oauth_signature_method": "HMAC-SHA1", "oauth_timestamp": "my-oauth-timestamp", "oauth_token": "my-oauth-token", "oauth_version": "1.0"]]
```

I searched for days, but didnt found anything... please somebody help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `curl` command is only creating 1 `Authorized` header, not multiple headers like the `HTTPotion` code.

This should work:

```
HTTPotion.get("https://api.digits.com/1.1/sdk/account.json",
              [headers: ["Authorization": ~s|OAuth  oauth_signature="my-oauth-signature",oauth_nonce="my-oauty-nonce",oauth_timestamp="my-oauth-timestamp",oauth_consumer_key="my-oauth-consumer-key",oauth_token="my-oauth-token",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"|]])
```

Comment: thank you @Dogbert for very quick reply i tried your code but got this response : `code` ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in anonymous fn/1 in HTTPotion.process_arguments/3
    (httpotion) lib/httpotion.ex:356: anonymous fn("Authorization") in HTTPotion.process_arguments/3
       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1088: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (httpotion) lib/httpotion.ex:356: HTTPotion.process_arguments/3
    (httpotion) lib/httpotion.ex:356: HTTPotion.request/3 `code`